# Sort and Swap using byte pointers to array types

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort arrays by using `byte pointers`.. By this, I mean I don't want to know the given type of the array. Sort of a generic-sort without templates.

So far, my algorithm (bubble sort) seems to be working with sorting only Integer arrays. However, I cannot figure out why the same algorithm won't sort char or float arrays.. I took my algorithm from an old post I wrote with the solution being: http://ideone.com/UagOGp and changed it to use bytes instead..

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void Print(T* arr, std::size_t size)
{
    std::cout<<"[";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<arr[size - 1]<<"]\n";
}

void PtrSwap(std::uint8_t* a, std::uint8_t* b, std::size_t size_ptr)
{
    std::uint8_t t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_ptr; ++i)
    {
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = t;
    }
}

void PtrSort(std::uint8_t* list, std::size_t length, std::size_t size_ptr, bool (*comparator)(void* a, void* b))
{
    int size = length * size_ptr;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i += size_ptr)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < size - i - size_ptr; j += size_ptr)
        {
            if (comparator(&list[j + size_ptr], &list[j]))
            {
                PtrSwap(&list[j + size_ptr], &list[j], size_ptr);
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IntComparator(void* a, void* b)
{
    return *static_cast<int*>(a) < *static_cast<int*>(b);
}

bool CharComparator(void* a, void* b)
{
    return *static_cast<char*>(a) < *static_cast<char*>(b);
}

bool FloatComparator(void* a, void* b)
{
    return *static_cast<float*>(a) < *static_cast<float*>(b);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 9, 7, 2, 4, 10, 6, 5, 8};
    PtrSort((std::uint8_t*)&arr[0], 10, sizeof(int), &IntComparator);
    Print(arr, 10);

    char arr2[] = {'a', 'j', 'c', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'f'};
    PtrSort((std::uint8_t*)&arr2[0], 10, sizeof(char), &CharComparator);
    Print(arr2, 10);

    float arr3[] = {1.0, 1.3, 1.9, 1.7, 1.2, 1.4, 1.1, 1.6, 1.5, 1.8};
    PtrSort((std::uint8_t*)&arr3[0], 10, sizeof(float), &FloatComparator);
    Print(arr3, 10);
}
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**.. The above code will work.

Comment: Wait, why are you doing this? Why are you using `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I'm doing it for an experiment and so that I can port it to a language that does NOT have templates or generics. I used `reinterpret_cast` to change the void pointer back to its real type. Guess I could change it to `static_cast` but I doubt it'd make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean by *port*? And what language are we talking about?

Comment: `PascalScript` and by port I mean translate.

Comment: On `PtrSwap` you are iterating but each iteration does the same thing. What did you mean to do?

Comment: Is `std::iter_swap` just not good enough?

Comment: @WhozCraig `iter_swap` is strongly typed, I doubt the OP can use it here.

Comment: @Nick that fixed it! :D I updated the post to reflect the change I made to `PtrSwap`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Are you sure the `<=` in `PtrSwap` is correct?

Comment: @dyp I didn't mean as a replacement, I meant inside , but I see your point. And I concur that `<=` seems odd.

Comment: I changed the `<=` It all works now: http://ideone.com/2vU6nb :D

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames You're approaching [`qsort` from the C Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) btw.